# The time index of an R ts object is modified by floor?

Tags: r, time-series

I cannot figure out what is happening here. I define a time series object `x` as below, and two other related time series:

```
x <- structure(2017, .Tsp = c(2017.41666666667, 2017.41666666667, 12), class = "ts")
y <- floor(x)
z <- x-y
```

The three time series should have the same time index. However I get the following:

```
> time(x)-time(y)
     Jun
2017   0

> time(x)-time(z)
integer(0)
Warning message:
In .cbind.ts(list(e1, e2), c(deparse(substitute(e1))[1L], deparse(substitute(e2))[1L]),  :
  non-intersecting series

> time(x)[1]-time(z)[1]
[1] 3.183231e-12
```

Is this a bug in R?

(using R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21), Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 ).

Comment: `all.equal(time(x), time(z))` is TRUE. Looks like a precision issue.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a 32-bit float precision issue. But why would the index be recalculated at all when subtracting two time series with identical indices?